# not able to change my EMAIL_HOST_USER i django

Tags: python, django, reset-password

I am making a website in Django where I have used SMPT mail to send mail to user to change password when forgotten,
everything is working right so far, but now I want to change my `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, when I change it, it doesn't send any mail to user, please tell me how can I change it

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abc@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =  '********'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I want to change "abc@gmail.com" to "xyz@gmail.com"

please help

Answer (score 0):

Log in with a xuz@gmail.com in Google and go to the [this link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) and turn on the less secure apps option to allow you to send e-mails

Comment: I already did this, but it is not still working